# Sharepoint 2016 feature pack 1 sequence

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

We have a SharePoint 2016 enterprise RC version (16.0.4327.1000) installed.

Now we are planning to upgrade to Feature pack1 and have following queries:

1. What is changed here > Is feature pack same as service pack?
2. If we install feature pack, with this include RTM and subsequent updates?
3. Also is RC to Feature pack upgrade supported or , we must have RTM version for upgrading to Feature pack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not upgrade from RC to RTM, you should start fresh on RTM. This means taking database backups from say SharePoint 2013, not the RC.

Once you've got your brand new RTM farm, you can just install the November 2016 PU and you'll be all set.

Comment: So I must have do fresh sharepoint installation with RTM binaries? Is there no way to upgrade from RC to RTM ? and then Feature pack(Nov 16 PU ) :(

Comment: Not in a way that is supported.